# MacBook Pro 2016 USB-C to HDMI (Apple Multiport Adapter) problem

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, hdmi

My MacBook won't display anything connected through an **USB-C Digital AV Multiport Adapter** to HDMI display. I have tried with many (Dell, Samsung, Acer, Iyama, LG, from the local store) external displays.

Sometimes (after a restart, with SMC reset) it works for 5 seconds and suddenly stops. It does not even show the external display in the preferences.

Do you know how to fix it?

Hardware details:

- USB-C Digital AV Multiport Adapter from Apple (MJ1K2ZM/A)
- MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2016, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports)
- 2,4 GHz Intel Core i7
- 16 GB 1867 MHz LPDDR3
- Intel Iris Graphics 540 1536 MB

*I have noticed one thing - when I disconnect the HDMI cable the display says "No HDMI Cable" when I connect it back it says "Entering Power Save Mode".*

Comment: Did you make sure everything is fully plugged in? Try playing with each of the connections. Also curious what your display settings say.

Comment: @JBallin I have played with all the connections with many displays. How should I check my display settings?

Comment: Maybe go to Apple Store so somebody can look at it in person. Also maybe try another adapter/hdmi cable.

Comment: @JBallin I will do it tomorrow :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to replace the adapter. It seems the one I was using was broken. Now everything is fine and the display displays :).